# Resizing WebView to HTML Content Height

Tags: java, javafx

I have a WebView that is shown in a popup (PopOver to be exact, but that shouldn't matter). I am attempting to resize the WebView to match the height of one div in the HTML-content. I have a working solution, with one exception, **the first time** I show the WebView in the popup, the height is incorrect. All subsequent attempts will resize the WebView correctly.

Here's the relevant code I have:

```
ChangeListener listener = new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
            try {
                Object result = webView.getEngine().executeScript("document.getElementById('txt').clientHeight");
                if (result instanceof Integer) {
                    Integer i = (Integer) result;
                    double height = (double) i;
                    height = height + 20;
                    webView.setPrefHeight(height);
                    webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().removeListener(this);
                }
            } catch (JSException ignored) {}
            callback.invoke();
        }
    }
};

webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(listener);
webView.getEngine().loadContent(some_content);
```

Anyone have ideas why this method returns incorrect (too large in my case) results for the first time I show the WebView, and how to circumvent it?

Comment: You might be interest in voting on this (currently unresolved/unscheduled) feature request: [RT-25005 Automatic preferred sizing of WebView](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-25005)

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks for digging that up, I gave my vote for it.

Comment: I have the same issue.  The problem appears to be `webView.setPrefHeight(height);` occurs as a background process and it's not synchronous, so it's the cart (`loadContent(...)`) before the horse (`setPrefHeight(...)`) scenario.  What's most troublesome is I cannot find a way to capture that the `setPrefHeight(...)` has completed.  You can add a `DoubleProperty` listener, but it seems to sporadically fire a few times with invalid values before eventually setting, or at least that's the behavior I observe with `autosize()`.